# Payment gateway integration in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, paypal, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I needed to integrate payment gateway in an application and I implemented [DoDirectPayment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment), but I have some question in my mind.

- What are the pros and cons of doing so?
- Will apple reject application as I have not used InAppPurchage?
- What will be the best option if you suggest, to integrate?
- Does these payment gateways are not allowed in an iPhone application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what the payment is for.

If it's for purchasing physical (non-digital) out of app things then it's ok to use.

Comment: And what if the application make both physical and digital goods purchase?

Comment: what type of digital goods? if the digital goods are to be used in the app you have to use Apple' in-app purchase.

Comment: like music, and, problem is if application sell music and t-shirt both, what should we do then.

Comment: t-shirt I can't see a problem with. If the music on a physical CD then that would be fine too. If the music is digital (e.g. mp3 format) and if the app couldn't play the music you are selling then I think you'd be okay. My understanding is that in-app purchases are for anything that is used/consumed in-app.